# Using java to communicate with a PHP script on my server

Tags: java, php

I need to be able to access my database, which in it's own isn't hard as java can directly access it. I want to, however, use a php script to access it, as I need to insert stuff into the database as well, and I don't want to have the username and password of a read-write accoutn for my database in my java code. If someone decompiles it, he can just access my database and do stuff with it...

So basicly, I want to use a PHP script and send $_POST request info from my java code to my php script

(yes, java, not javascript ;-) )

Comment: So you want to do this to be able to hide db username/pwd? Why not just encrypt the pwd and save yourself the trouble?

Comment: Why not configure the username and password in the Java app? Either a config file, or in Context.xml if it's a web app, or command line flags -Dmy.db.user=something if it's a standalone app? Lots of possibilities.

Comment: Sounds like the PHP part will act like an API. You can communicate from any platform using SOAP or something similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, no problem. Use a URLConnection with `setDoOutput(true)`, and get its output stream for the POST.

Of course, your PHP script should make sure that all data which is sent is sane, as anyone could send such a request to your PHP script. (Or you would need some way for the Java application to authenticate itself to the PHP script, which simply shifts the problem of hiding these credentials instead of the database ones.)

Answer (score 0):

You should store DB credentials in configuration file to avoid embedding them directly into the code.